# No access to the external network from Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an issue with the requests to the several external resources from the docker container at the server

Here is the docker-compose file (nothing unusual):

```
services:
  nodejs:
    image: image_name
    volumes:
      - ./config/config.json:/app/config/config.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=my_domain.com"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - int_network

networks:
  int_network:
    external: true
```

The problem is that inside the container several requests are dying by the timeout, for example

```
/app # curl https://google.com --max-time 15 -v
*   Trying 74.125.205.138:443...
* Connected to google.com (74.125.205.138) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Operation timed out after 15000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

But if I'm trying to access google.com with http - everything is fine

And even if I cannot access https://google.com I can access https://yahoo.com - so only few sites are affected.

Everything is OK at the host machine.

`docker inspect` for the network:

```
  {
    "Name": "int_network",
    "Id": "f1147fd7d4cdc63f82aaa6bc9b71c79713f9e590d7c3cb8a2aa07339456413e2",
    "Created": "2020-07-16T07:42:41.949623342Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Options": {},
      "Config": [
        {
          "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
          "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
      "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
      // Containers list
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
  }
]
```

Any suggestions? Maybe is is an SSL issue?

Comment: Do you have this issue with Google only? Or the issue exists with any site using SSL, including StackOverFlow?

Comment: Not only google.com, it started with the https://api.opentok.com, then I've tried different popular sites

Comment: And what if you `curl` google in your host? I think your internet connection may have some problems and your ISP is bothering you.

Comment: Everything is OK on the host machine. It is not an internet provider issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the MTU issue. Creating new docket network resolves the issue